# Manipulating a 'dynamic' array in javascript

Tags: arrays, sorting

As part of my **nightwatchjs** testing script, I have a 'dynamic' array that I would like to add a character to.

So, at the moment my array has a value of **`4000`**, but I would like this to read **`4,000`**.

This means that I need to add a **`,`** to my array.

The issue I have however, is that this value could change the next time I run the test script, so it could be **`10000`** or **`100000`**.

So I suppose what I'm asking is whether it's possible to *"select a value **3 elements from the end** of my array?"*

So no matter what or how many elements are in the array, the array will read xx,000.

Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does this array have a single value? If so, why is it an array instead of just a variable?

You can use toLocaleString() to add commas to a numeric value, but it will return a string and not a number.

```
let arr = [4000]
let num = arr[0]
let commas = num.toLocaleString()
console.log(commas)
// "4,000"
```

Comment: Ah no, as I mentioned in my question this array is a dynamic value so could be 4000, 10,000, 100,000, etc rather than a fixed value.

Comment: the answer still works whether it is dynamic or static. if the array consist of only 1 value (since an array is by definition a LIST of values separated by commas), select the first value and use the toLocaleString() method. 
`nameOfYourArray[0].toLocaleString();`